# Typescript syntaxError: Unexpected token ':' & No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to learn typescript but when I run following in vs code it gives me an error.

```
let firstName: string = "Dylan";
console.log(firstName);
```

```
syntaxError: Unexpected token ':' &
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

I installed typescript by

`npm install -g typescript` in terminal

`tsc --version` is: `Version 4.6.4`

Why is my typescript code not running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are running the TypeScript directly rather than transpiling first.

Running the following command, provided your [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) is configured correctly, will emit valid JavaScript that you can run with Node, for example.

```
npx tsc
```

If you would like to run it without transpiling first, a tool called [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) exists for that. You can install it globally with `npm install -g ts-node.

To run a file, the following command will work:

```
ts-node {file-name}
```